# Ruby: When defining a class is "initialize" for convenience?

Tags: ruby

I'm new to programming and am trying to figure out the purpose of "initialize" in creating a class.

Here's an example:

```
class Person
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
    @pet = nil
    @home = 'NYC'
  end
end
```

So initializing is to create a bunch of attributes that I can pull out directly by saying `Person.name` and `Person.pet` and `Person.home` right? Is "initialize" just to compact a bunch of variables into one place? Would I accomplish the same thing doing this:

```
class Person     
  pet = nil    
  home = 'NYC'    
  #not so sure how to replicate the @name here.    
end
```

Wouldn't I be able to access the values with `Person.pet` and `Person.home` the same way as I would in the first code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a little tricky in Ruby (as opposed to, say, Java) since both classes and instances of classes are actual objects at runtime.  As such, a class has its own set of variables, and each instance of that class also gets its own set of variables (distinct from the class's variables).

When you say

```
class Person
  pet = nil
end
```

You're setting a variable, pet, which is local only to the class object called `Person`.

The way to manipulate the variables of an *instance* of a class is to use the variables in *methods*:

```
class Person
  def initialize
    pet = nil
  end
end
```

Here, pet refers to a local variable of a given *instance* of `Person`.  Of course, this pet variable is pretty useless as defined, since it's just a local variable that goes away after the `initialize` function completes.  The way to make this variable persist for the lifetime of the instance is to make it an *instance variable*, which you accomplish by prefixing it with a `@`.  And thus we arrive at your first initialize:

```
class Person
  def initialize
    @pet = nil
    # And so on
  end
end
```

So, as to why you need `initialize`.  Since the only way to set the instance variables of instances of `Person` is within methods of `Person`, this initialization needs to be in *some* method.  `initialize` is just the convenient name for a method which is automatically called when your instance is first created.

Comment: Yes, best explanation I've heard in 6 years doing ruby

Answer (score 3):

Initialize is a method usually referred as an object constructor. It is used when you call `Person.new("Bob")` and it will give you an instance of that `Person` object. The @ symbol you see before the variables in the initialize makes the variable an instance variable meaning that variable will only be accessed once you have an instance of that object and it will stay there for the lifetime of that instance.

For example

```
person = Person.new("Bob")
person.name #Will output Bob
person.home #Will output NYC
```

Classes are objects and doing this:

```
class Person
  pet = nil
  home = 'NYC'
end
```

is just creating local variables pet and home and will be outside of the scope of the class. This means calling `Person.pet` and `Person.home` will just give you an error. I would suggest do a little reading on Object Oriented Programming (OOP) and if you have any more questions throw them in stackoverflow :D

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong: in order to access the variables like he describes, he will need the attr_accessor method in the body of the class definition, yes?

Comment: so while functions can be defined similarly to how I just defined variables (freely without initialize), self calling variables need to be defined within initialize?

Comment: @Edmund, Not necessarily. Ruby is a pretty loose, dynamic language in that you can define an instance variable in any function of the class at any time. So for example: def doStuff @ newVar = "yay" end

Comment: @Teeg I just tried what you're talking about. Yeh, I typed `attr_accessor :home` and then tried `puts person.home`, but it was empty. So I'm guessing even though `person` is an instance of Class `Person`, when variables are defined openly like that their values don't get inherited by the instance. I had to add a line `person.home = 'LA'` in order to receive a value for person.home when printing it

Comment: @Teeg so the @newVar = "yay" (assume it's in the class Person) be accessible if I type `person.doStuff.newVar ?

Comment: @Edmund Yes, it would be accessible like that, only if you had a getter method defined for @ newVar. The attr_accessor :newVar line would create that for you, or you could create your own function called "def newVar". My original example was just showing that you can defined instance variables outside of the initialize function. Also something interesting to note is that ruby returns the last value of a function, so technically speaking you could person.doStuff, which will return the value of @ newVar. That's getting a little off topic from your orignal question, but thought I'd point it out.